# Open a URL in QGIS from form (or using actions) in Linux

Tags: qgis, actions

Does anyone know the correct instructions to open a URL as an action (or from a form) using Arch Linux?

In Windows it's as simple as using 'Open' in the action type, and then [%'field containing URL'%] in the action text.

In Linux this just yields a `Malformed URL` error. The QGIS guidance suggests xdg-open[%'field containing URL'%], but that just yields `Unable to run command xdg-open[%'field containing URL'%]`

I've tried the same commands under 'Unix' and 'Generic' action types, but to no different effect.

Comment: This should work with type open (tested on QGIS 3.8.3). Note that `'` refers for string if you want refer to field you have to use `"` or just write the name of field without quotes `[%field containing URL%]`. Also aviod the spaces in field name if there are any.

Comment: @OtoKaláb Just to clarify, you've tested this on Arch Linux? The ```'``` and spaces were just my way of trying to get across the idea of "whatever the field name is", so there's no ```'``` or space in my actual action-text